# Replacing a string parameter with a List for a recursive method

Tags: java, string, list, recursion, permutation

I was struggeling with a probably simple problem for the last 3 hours. I rewrote a class and replaced 2 String parameters with Lists.
The problem is, that when calling the rekursive method you add 1 character to the first string parameter. And when the length of the parameter hits the length of 7 it prints it out. The string never gets longer than 7.
I replaced it with a Integer List since the String only consisted of numbers.
The List though keeps getting longer and longer and I have no idea why. I hope I explained everything properly. If not, ask me please.

The question is probably super easy to answer for you guys.

Here is the first class, that works.

```
    package Uebung4;

public class PermAll_Alt {

static int counter = 0;

private static void permutation(String word, String str) {

    int n = str.length();

    // System.out.println(str + " Str");
    // System.out.println(word + " word");

    if (n == 0) {

        if (

        (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(0, 1))) > (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(1, 2)))
                && (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(1, 2))) < (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(2, 3)))
                && (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(2, 3))) > (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(3, 4)))
                && (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(3, 4))) < (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(4, 5)))
                && (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(4, 5))) > (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(5, 6)))
                && (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(5, 6))) < (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(6, 7)))

        ) {
            // System.out.println(word);
            counter++;
        }

    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // System.out.println("Word: " +word+"\t str charat:
            // "+str.charAt(i));
            // System.out.println(word + str.charAt(i) + " \t combined");

            System.out.println("substr(0,i): " + str.substring(0, i) + " substr(i+1) " + str.substring(i + 1));
            permutation(word + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1));
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    permutation("", "1234567");
    System.out.println("Anzahl:  " + counter);
}
}
```

And here is my class that I edited:

```
package Uebung4;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PermAll {

static int counter = 0;

private static void permutation(List<Integer> wordList, List<Integer> lis) {

  //  List<Integer> wordList2 = cloneList(wordList);

    int n = lis.size();

    if (n == 0) {
        String word = "";
        for (Integer i : wordList) {
            word += i;
        }


        if ((Integer.parseInt(word.substring(0, 1))) > (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(1, 2)))
                && (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(1, 2))) < (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(2, 3)))
                && (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(2, 3))) > (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(3, 4)))
                && (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(3, 4))) < (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(4, 5)))
                && (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(4, 5))) > (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(5, 6)))
                && (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(5, 6))) < (Integer.parseInt(word.substring(6, 7)))

        ) {
            System.out.println(word);
            // convertToDU(word);
            counter++;
        }

    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            List<Integer> tempLis = new ArrayList<>();

           //String tempString = "";

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                tempLis.add(lis.get(j));
            }
            System.out.print("str.substr(0,i): " + tempLis+"\t");


            for (int k = i + 1; k < lis.size(); k++) {
                tempLis.add(lis.get(k));
                System.out.print(""+lis.get(k)+", ");
            }
            System.out.println(tempLis);

            // System.out.println("word "+wordList + "\t charat:
            // "+lis.get(i));
            wordList.add(lis.get(i));

          //  System.out.println(wordList + " \t kombiniert");

            permutation(wordList, tempLis);
            // permutation(word + lis.get(i),tempLis);
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int anzahl = 7;

    for (int i = 1; i <= anzahl; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    String para = "";
    for (Integer i : list) {
        para += i;
    }

    List<Integer> abc = new ArrayList<>();

    permutation(abc, list);
    System.out.println("Anzahl:  " + counter);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution: I took the code that was doing the recursive call in the String args version and copied the logic to the List args version:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // create a copy of wordList
            List<Integer> permWordList = new ArrayList<Integer>(wordList);

            // equiv to "word + str.charAt(i)"
            permWordList.add(strLis.get(i));  

            // create a copy of lis
            List<Integer> permStrList = new ArrayList<Integer>(lis);

            // equiv to "str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1)"
            permStrList.remove(i);  

            permutation(permWordList, permStrList);
        }
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine. Thanks a lot! Can you also give me some explanation, why I had to copy the List "lis"? Genius idea with removing just the element i in the one list instead of counting around i. I feel stupid for not seeing that.

Comment: you need to create copies of wordList and lis so that you get a fresh copy with each iteration (otherwise, lis will get smaller and smaller)
lastly, please show your appreciation by accepting and/or upvoting...